# I am having an issue with jquery load function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a shopping cart where the quantities or cart items can be adjusted or be removed via ajax so the page doesn't have to be refresh to reflect the changes etc.

I have an external shopping_cart.js that handles all the shopping cart js side of things. When i adjust cart item quantities i use DOM innerHTML on ajax success function to reflect the changes to the user, but for entirely removing a cart items i am using jquery load function to load an update_cart.php file into a container div element which displays the updated cart contents in a mouse over cart quick link when ever the user clicks to remove/add/minus a cart item.

Being that i am using jquery.load to load cart_update.php script, i have to include the external shopping_cart.js in the cart_update.php script for all the JS to work when the script is loaded, but the problem i am having is that when i include the js file in the cart_update.php and load it with jquery it seems to loop through the javascript multiple times each when i click any of the add/minus/remove buttons for each product, and compounding each loop with each click.

For example, when i click add qty the first time, the cart quantity will add one additional item, when i click again, it will loop through 2 additional items, then 4, 8, 16 and so on. But if i place the external js file in the main php page file and not in the cart_update script it works as normally after a page refresh and doesn't loop, though obviously the javascript doesn't work when the shopping cart is loaded with jquery.load when i try to remove a cart item as it cant access the js file as it's not included in the cart_update.php

I m really not sure where i am going wrong here. I am only a novice programmer

cart_update.php

```
<!-- Display cart contents -->

<script src="js/shopping_cart.js"></script>

<?php 
// Call session start when the script is loaded via jquery.load
if (isset($_SESSION)){
} else {
    session_start();
}

require_once "config.php";
$session_id = session_id();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM shopping_cart WHERE session_id='$session_id'";

$stmt = $PDOconnection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();

if($rowCount < 1 ){
    echo "Your cart is empty.";
} else {

    $points = 0;

    while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $ui          = $result['ui'];
        $item_points = $result['item_points'];

        // Display cart item name, price, quantity and amount of points earned
        echo "<br>" . $result['item_name'] . " $" . number_format($result['item_price'],2) . " Qty: " . $result['item_quantity'] . " <a href='#' class='remove_item' data-ui='$ui'> X </a><br>";  

        $points = $points + number_format($item_points, 1);
    }

    echo "<hr />";

    if (isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
        echo "You have earned $points points with this purchase!";
    } else {
        echo "Sign up to recieve $points points with this purchase! <a href'#'>What's this?</a>";
    }

    echo "<hr />";

    echo "<a href='cart.php'>Check Out</a>";
}
?>
```

shopping_cart.js

```
function cart_data(cartData) {

    // Get data values
    var $item_stock_type  = cartData.getAttribute('data-stock-type');
    var $item_ui          = cartData.getAttribute('data-stock-ui');

    // Set value as one. As it's signle qty when adding to cart from the product list   
    var $item_qty = 1;

    $(document).ready(function(e){

        // Send data for processing in shopping_cart.php
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/shopping_cart.php",
            data: { item_stock_type: $item_stock_type, item_ui: $item_ui, item_qty: $item_qty },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            success: function(data, response){

                document.getElementById("cart_total").innerHTML = data.cart_total;
                document.getElementById("shoppingcart_link_quantity").innerHTML = data.cart_qty + '<br />';

                switch (data.success)
                {
                case 0:
                    modal({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Ooops',
                        text: data.error_message,
                        center: true,
                        animate: true,                  
                    });
                    break;

                case 1:
                    modal({
                        type: 'alert',
                        title: '',
                        text: data.user_message,
                        center: true,
                        animate: true,
                        autoclose: true,
                    });  
                    break;

                case 2:
                    modal({
                        type: 'alert',
                        title: '',
                        text: data.user_message,
                        center: true,
                        animate: true,
                    });   
                    break;
                }
                // Update Shopping cart contents
                $("#shopping_cart_container").load("php/update_cart.php");              
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error){

                var $jxr = jqXHR;
                var $status = status;
                var $error = error;

                // Display error message to user
                modal({
                 type: 'error',
                 title: 'Ooops!',
                 text: 'An Error has occured: <br><br>' + jqXHR + ": " + status + "; " + error,
                 center: true,
                 animate: true,
                });

                // Log error message
            }
        });
    });
}

// Remove item from shopping cart quick link 
$(document).ready( function(){

    // Remove item from cart
    $(".remove_item").click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $ui = $(this).attr("data-ui");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/ajax.php',
            data: { remove_cart_item: $ui },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            success: function(data, response){

                document.getElementById("cart_total").innerHTML = data.cart_total;
                document.getElementById("shoppingcart_link_quantity").innerHTML = data.cart_qty + '<br />';

                switch (data.success)
                {
                case 0:
                    modal({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Ooops',
                        text: data.error_message,
                        center: true,
                        animate: true,              
                    });
                }
                // Update Shopping cart quick link contents
                $("#shopping_cart_container").load("php/update_cart.php");              
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error){

                var $jxr = jqXHR;
                var $status = status;
                var $error = error;

                // Display error message to user
                modal({
                 type: 'error',
                 title: 'Ooops!',
                 text: 'An Error has occured: <br><br>' + jqXHR + ": " + status + "; " + error,
                 center: true,
                 animate: true,
                });

                // Log error message
            }
        });
    });
});

// Add qty to shopping cart main page 
$(document).ready( function(){

    $(".add_item").click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $ui = $(this).attr("data-ui");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/ajax.php',
            data: { add_cart_item: $ui },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            success: function(data, response){

                switch (data.success)
                {

                case 0:

                    // No more stock. Notify user
                    modal({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Sorry',
                        text: data.error_message,
                        center: true,
                        animate: true,

                    });
                break;

                case 1:

                    // Update item qty
                    var $id = data.element_id;
                    document.getElementById("cart_total").innerHTML = data.cart_total;
                    document.getElementById("shoppingcart_link_quantity").innerHTML = data.cart_qty + '<br />';
                    document.getElementById($id).innerHTML = data.item_qty;

                    // Update Shopping cart quick link contents
                    $("#shopping_cart_container").load("php/update_cart.php");

                break;

                }           
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error){

                var $jxr = jqXHR;
                var $status = status;
                var $error = error;

                // Display error message to user
                modal({
                 type: 'error',
                 title: 'Ooops!',
                 text: 'An Error has occured: <br><br>' + jqXHR + ": " + status + "; " + error,
                 center: true,
                 animate: true,
                });

                // Log error message
            }
        });
    });
});

// Minus qty to shopping cart main page 
$(document).ready( function(){

    $(".minus_item").click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $ui = $(this).attr("data-ui");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/ajax.php',
            data: { minus_cart_item: $ui },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            success: function(data, response){


                switch (data.success)
                {

                case 0:
                break;

                case 1:

                    // Update item qty
                    var $id = data.element_id;
                    document.getElementById("cart_total").innerHTML = data.cart_total;
                    document.getElementById("shoppingcart_link_quantity").innerHTML = data.cart_qty + '<br />';
                    document.getElementById($id).innerHTML = data.item_qty;

                    // Update Shopping cart quick link contents
                    $("#shopping_cart_container").load("php/update_cart.php");

                break;
                }           
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error){

                var $jxr = jqXHR;
                var $status = status;
                var $error = error;

                // Display error message to user
                modal({
                 type: 'error',
                 title: 'Ooops!',
                 text: 'An Error has occured: <br><br>' + jqXHR + ": " + status + "; " + error,
                 center: true,
                 animate: true,
                });

                // Log error message
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: From the description, it sounds like you are attaching multiple event listeners when you redraw the cart data. Since you are using jQuery, look at https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: That seems logical. I will have a read of your link. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are attaching event listeners to dom elements that get removed when you overwrite them with `load`.

to fix, use event delegation to attach to a parent element that wont get removed.

eg, replace:

```
 $(".remove_item").click( function(e){...
```

with:

```
 $("#shopping_cart_container").on('click','.remove_item', function(e){...
```

more info: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly. So with event delegation i am basically attaching the event handler to a parent element that's always "guaranteed to be present", so the event handlers can't be overwritten with load? though obviously making sure the parent element is not a part of the the script to be loaded

Comment: yes, thats essentially it. the parent element chosen can be as high up the chain as needed (eg `body`), but you should be as specific as you can, for performance reasons

Answer (score 1):

1. Add your javascript only once to the page,  don't send it with every ajax response. This way you will not have multiple event handlers attached to the add button.
2. In the script change the way you add the remove item handler to `$(document).on ("click", ".minus_item", function(e){...})` because otherwise you will lose event handlers every time you replace basket content from ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

You end up with several events on the same elements every time you define the cart_data function. One solution to this is to simply reassign it if it exists.

So instead of this

```
function cart_data(cartData) {
     ...
}
```

you could do this

```
var cart_data = cart_data || function(cartData) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also, if you are replacing the elements that you bind the events to, it is better to use event delegation.